# REST API - Swagger - Don't understand why "Not a valid parameter definition"

Tags: rest, api, swagger

I face issue with my swagger file :

```
swagger: '2.0'
paths:
  /currencies:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
      summary: 'list currencies summary'
      x-auth-type: None
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      produces:
        - application/json
      description: 'list currencies description'
  '/currencies/{currencieId}':
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
      description: 'Single currency description'
      parameters:
        - name: currencieId
          in: path
          allowMultiple: false
          required: true
          type: string
          description: 'paramter description'
      summary: 'Single currency'
      x-auth-type: None
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      produces:
        - application/json
info:
  title: MDM
  version: v1
```

Here is my issue :

✖ Swagger Error
Not a valid parameter definition
Jump to line 20
Details
 Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
 params: Array [0]
message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
 path: Array [5]
0:  "paths"
1:  "/currencies/{currencieId}"
2:  "get"
3:  "parameters"
4:  "0"
schemaId:  "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#"
 inner: Array [2]
level: 900
type:  "Swagger Error"
description:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
lineNumber: 20

[Issue in swagger editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrXHU.png)

I am a bit lost with that ....

Thanks for your help.

Julien

Answer (score 2):

Remove `allowMultiple: false` from the definition of the `currencieId` parameter.  That eliminates the error.

The `allowMultiple` keyword does not exist in the [OpenAPI (fka Swagger) Specification 2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md). It was used in [v1.2](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#user-content-parameterAllowMultiple), but in 2.0 it was replaced with `type: array` and [`collectionFormat`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-parameterCollectionFormat).

Answer (score 0):

allowMultiple: false is not correct